# Error C++ LNK2019 s¡mbolo externo

Tags: c++, archivo, qt

Tengo un proyecto para una materia. Estoy trabajando en QT quick con C++ y qml, e implemento el uso de archivos y archivos de índices, y tengo un error que me tiene fastidiado.

El error me lo marca en la clase que maneja los archivos de mi clase `Medico`

`MedicoFileManager.h`

```
#ifndef MEDICOFILEMANAGER_H
#define MEDICOFILEMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

#include "IndiceTupla.h"
#include "nombre.h"
#include "medico.h"

class MedicoFileManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MedicoFileManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MedicoFileManager();

    void agregarDato(const Medico&);
    void agregarDato(const std::list<Medico>&);

    void eliminarDato(const int&);

    int buscarDato(const Medico&);

    std::list<Medico> aLista();

    void limpiar();

    void comprimir();

public slots:
    std::list<Medico*> listaAQML(int, int);

private:
    std::string datosFileName;
    std::string indCedulaFileName;
    std::string indNombreFileName;

    std::fstream datosFile;
    std::fstream indicePorCedulaFile;
    std::fstream indicePorNombreFile;

    std::list<IndiceTupla<>> indicePorCedulaLista;
    std::list<IndiceTupla<Nombre>> indicePorNombreLista;

    void reIndizar();

    template <class T>
    std::list<IndiceTupla<T>>& ArchivoALista(std::fstream&, std::list<IndiceTupla<T>>&);

    template <class T>
    std::fstream& listaAArchivo(const std::list<T>&, std::fstream&);

    template <class T>
    int getIndice(const std::list<T>&, const T&);
};

#endif // MEDICOFILEMANAGER_H
```

`MedicoFileManager.cpp`

```
#include "medicofilemanager.h"

MedicoFileManager::MedicoFileManager(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), datosFileName("medicos.file"),
    indCedulaFileName("medicosIndiceCedula.index"),
    indNombreFileName("medicosIndiceNombre.index")
{
}

MedicoFileManager::~MedicoFileManager()
{
    if (datosFile.is_open())
    {
        datosFile.close();
    }
    if (indicePorCedulaFile.is_open())
    {
        indicePorCedulaFile.close();
    }
    if (indicePorNombreFile.is_open())
    {
        indicePorNombreFile.close();
    }
}

void MedicoFileManager::agregarDato(const Medico &miMedico)
{
    std::list<Medico> miLista;

    miLista.push_back(miMedico);

    agregarDato(miLista);
}

void MedicoFileManager::agregarDato(const std::list<Medico> &miLista)
{
    datosFile.open(datosFileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);

    if (!datosFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    listaAArchivo(miLista, datosFile);

    datosFile.close();

    //reIndizar();
}

void MedicoFileManager::eliminarDato(const int &indice)
{
    for (auto it(indicePorCedulaLista.begin()); it != indicePorCedulaLista.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->getIndice() == indice)
        {
            indicePorCedulaLista.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }

    indicePorCedulaFile.open(indCedulaFileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

    if (!indicePorCedulaFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    //listaAArchivo(indicePorCedulaLista, indicePorNombreFile);

    indicePorCedulaFile.close();

    for (auto it(indicePorNombreLista.begin()); it != indicePorNombreLista.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->getIndice() == indice)
        {
            indicePorNombreLista.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }

    indicePorNombreFile.open(indNombreFileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

    if (!indicePorNombreFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    //listaAArchivo(indicePorNombreLista, indicePorNombreFile);

    indicePorNombreFile.close();

    datosFile.open(datosFileName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);

    if (!datosFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    datosFile.seekp(indice);

    datosFile<< "0";

    datosFile.close();
}

int MedicoFileManager::buscarDato(const Medico &medico)
{
    for (auto it(indicePorCedulaLista.begin()); it != indicePorCedulaLista.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->getData() == medico.getCedula())
        {
            return it->getIndice();
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

std::list<Medico> MedicoFileManager::aLista()
{
    datosFile.open(datosFileName, std::ios_base::in);

    if (!datosFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    std::list<Medico> miLista;
    Medico miMedico;
    std::string miStr;

    while (!datosFile.eof())
    {
        std::getline(datosFile, miStr, '#');
        if (miStr.empty())
        {
            continue;
        }
        std::stringstream miStrStream(miStr);

        std::getline(miStrStream, miStr, '*');

        if (miStr == "0")
        {
            continue;
        }

        miStrStream >> miMedico;
        miLista.push_back(miMedico);
    }

    datosFile.close();

    return miLista;
}

void MedicoFileManager::limpiar()
{
    remove(datosFileName.c_str());
    reIndizar();
    listaAArchivo(aLista(), datosFile);
}

void MedicoFileManager::comprimir()
{
    reIndizar();
    listaAArchivo(aLista(), datosFile);
}

void MedicoFileManager::reIndizar()
{
    datosFile.open(datosFileName, std::ios_base::in);

    if (!datosFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    std::string miStr;
    Medico miMedico;
    int miIndice;

    while (!datosFile.eof())
    {
        miIndice = datosFile.tellg();

        std::getline(datosFile, miStr, '#');

        if (miStr.empty())
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::stringstream miStrStream(miStr);

        std::getline(miStrStream, miStr, '*');

        if (miStr == "0")
        {
            continue;
        }

        miStrStream >> miMedico;

        indicePorCedulaLista.push_back(IndiceTupla<>(miIndice, miMedico.getCedula()));
        indicePorNombreLista.push_back(IndiceTupla<Nombre>(miIndice, *miMedico.getNombre()));
    }

    indicePorCedulaFile.open(indCedulaFileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

    if (!indicePorCedulaFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    listaAArchivo(indicePorCedulaLista, indicePorCedulaFile); //ERROR

    indicePorCedulaFile.close();

    indicePorNombreFile.open(indNombreFileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);

    if (!indicePorNombreFile.is_open())
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("No se abrio el archivo para añadir medicos");
    }

    //listaAArchivo(indicePorNombreLista, indicePorNombreFile);

    indicePorNombreFile.close();


    datosFile.close();
}

template <class T>
std::list<IndiceTupla<T>> &MedicoFileManager::ArchivoALista(std::fstream &miArchivo, std::list<IndiceTupla<T>> &miLista)
{
    std::string miStr;
    T miDato;

    while (!miArchivo.eof())
    {
        std::getline(miArchivo, miStr, '#');
        std::stringstream miStrStream(miStr);

        std::getline(miStrStream, miStr, '*');

        if (miStr == "0")
        {
            continue;
        }

        miStrStream >> miDato;
        miLista.push_back(miDato);
    }

    return miLista;
}

template <class T>
std::fstream& MedicoFileManager::listaAArchivo(const std::list<T> &miLista, std::fstream &miArchivo)
{
    for (auto it(miLista.begin()); it != miLista.end(); it++)
    {
        miArchivo << "1*" << *it << "#";
    }

    return miArchivo;
}

template <class T>
int MedicoFileManager::getIndice(const std::list<T> &miLista, const T &miDato)
{
    auto it(find(miLista.begin(), miLista.end(), miDato));

    if (it == miLista.end())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return it->getIndice();
}


//QML

std::list<Medico*> MedicoFileManager::listaAQML(int page, int pageSize)
{
    int startIndex = page * pageSize;
    int endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;

    if (startIndex < 0)
        startIndex = 0;

    std::list<Medico> lista = aLista();
    std::list<Medico*> sublista;

    auto it(lista.begin());
    std::advance(it, startIndex);

    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex && it != lista.end(); i++, it++) {
        sublista.push_back(new Medico(*it));
    }

    return sublista;
}
```

Pues el error radica en `listaAArchivo(indicePorCedulaLista, indicePorCedulaFile);` del método `reindizar()`, como también en el método eliminar, pero es básicamente el mismo error. Al compilar QT me lanza este error:

medicofilemanager.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: s¡mbolo externo "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > &,class IndiceTupla const &)" (??6@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV01@AEBV?$IndiceTupla@VQString@@@@@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la funci¢n "private: class std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl MedicoFileManager::listaAArchivo<class IndiceTupla >(class std::list<class IndiceTupla,class std::allocator<class IndiceTupla > > const &,class std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits > &)" (??$listaAArchivo@V?$IndiceTupla@VQString@@@@@MedicoFileManager@@AEAAAEAV?$basic_fstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEBV?$list@V?$IndiceTupla@VQString@@@@V?$allocator@V?$IndiceTupla@VQString@@@@@std@@@2@AEAV12@@Z)

He estado indagando e investigando y creo que el error está en el operador << de la clase de mis tuplas de índices

`indiceTupla.h`

```
#ifndef INDICETUPLA_H
#define INDICETUPLA_H

#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

template <class T = QString>
class IndiceTupla
{
public:
    IndiceTupla();
    IndiceTupla(const IndiceTupla&);
    IndiceTupla(const int&, const T&);
    IndiceTupla(const T&);

    int getIndice() const;
    void setIndice(const int&);

    T getData() const;
    void setData(const T&);

    IndiceTupla& operator = (const IndiceTupla&);
    IndiceTupla& operator = (const T&);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const IndiceTupla<T>&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, IndiceTupla<T>&);

private:
    int indice;
    T dato;
};

#endif // INDICETUPLA_H

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>::IndiceTupla() {}

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>::IndiceTupla(const IndiceTupla& other) : indice(other.indice), dato(other.dato) {}

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>::IndiceTupla(const int& index, const T& data) : indice(index), dato(data) {}

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>::IndiceTupla(const T& data) : dato(data) {}

template <class T>
int IndiceTupla<T>::getIndice() const
{
    return indice;
}

template <class T>
void IndiceTupla<T>::setIndice(const int& indice)
{
    this->indice = indice;
}

template <class T>
T IndiceTupla<T>::getData() const
{
    return dato;
}

template <class T>
void IndiceTupla<T>::setData(const T& dato)
{
    this->dato = dato;
}

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>& IndiceTupla<T>::operator=(const IndiceTupla& other)
{
    indice = other.indice;
    dato = other.dato;

    return *this;
}

template <class T>
IndiceTupla<T>& IndiceTupla<T>::operator=(const T& dato)
{
    this->dato = dato;

    return *this;
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IndiceTupla<T>& obj)
{
    os << obj.indice << "*";
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, QString>::value) {
        os << obj.dato.toStdString();
    } else
    {
        os << obj.dato;
    }
    return os;
}

template <class T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, IndiceTupla<T>& obj)
{
    std::string input;
    T miDato;
    std::getline(is, input, '*');
    obj.setIndice(std::stoi(input));
    is >> miDato;
    obj.setData(miDato);
    return is;
}
```

Le pregunte a chatGPT y me dio soluciones tontas, como lo es crear un operador de flujo para  QString tanto como para Nombre, pero eso es contraproducente.

Necesito help, básicamente si compila, pero no ejecuta, pero si quito esa línea de código si ejecuta el programa, les agradecería la ayuda. Cabe mencionar que en los archivos uso delimitadores de registros como `#` y de campos como `*`

Comment: Bienvenido. No puedes *declarar* una plantilla en un archivo e *implementarla* en otro. Con las plantillas es *todo* o *nada*. No puedes tener el código separado.